# Angular 6 + RxJs - Error handling for concatMap

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs6, concatmap

I'm still learning RxJs, and I'm trying to use concatMap() to NOT use nested subscriptions. I want the first call to run and then delay for a second or two (creating a database record before the second request) before running the second request. I also want to add error handling to each request specifically so I can catch errors for them individually.

So far, I have something that runs request 1, delays, and then runs request 2.

```
return this.request_1(postData).pipe(
      concatMap(res => of(res).pipe( delay( 2000 ) )),
      concatMap(res => this.request_2(parseInt(data.id), parseInt(model['_id'])) )
    );
```

What I'm wondering is -

1. can I use something like catchError() on each request?
2. is this correct if I want request 1 to complete before the second request runs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add a `catchError` to each request. but as long as you don't want to mutate the error object i would rather just have one `catchError` at the end of the pipe. that simply bubbles every error to the subscriber.

the error handling itself can then be done in the subscription

```
const source = of('World').pipe(
  concatMap(res => of(res).pipe(
    delay(2000),
    map(res => res += ' + concat 1')
  )),
  concatMap(res => of(res).pipe(
    map(res => res.h += ' + concat 2')
  )),
  catchError(err => throwError(err))
);

source.subscribe(
  x => console.log(x),
  error => console.log('error', error)
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6dign7